# best way to set a default value based on chained select

Tags: jquery, select, chained

im using two selects (chained) and each select has values of site and type, 3 sites, and 2 types. so Im setting a default value for the text input based on which is selected, I am going this route

```
if ("car" == $("#type").val() && "bmw" == $("#site").val()) $("#id").val('1565');
if ("truck" == $("#type").val() && "bmw" == $("#site").val()) $("#id").val('1565');
```

for example for the bmw site, and this would be repeated for the 2 other sites.

is a better way to go about this other than 6 if statements?

Comment: Use a switch-case structure? Nest some conditionals? A lookup table?

Comment: I guess this is what they mean by Yoda Conditions http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about making use of nested associative array - basically define your data then look it up...

```
var data = {
    car: {
        bmw: 1565,
        ford: 1900
    },
    truck: {
        bmw: 1565,
        volvo: 2001
    }
}

var typeValue = $("#type").val();
var siteValue = $("#site").val();

var dataValue = data[typeValue][siteValue];

if (dataValue) {
    $("#id").val(dataValue);
}
```